# Languages available as commentary in FIFA World Cup Brazil 2014

Tags: ps3, 2014-fifa-world-cup-brazil

In my FIFA 12 asian region I have several language options for text (German, English, Russian, etc). The game has fewer commentary options, but still has plenty like German, English, Spanish and Swedish.

What about World Cup 2014? Do different regions have different languages available?